# RoR - Active record query with exact match and 'LIKE'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

i need to build a ActiveRecord query in RoR environment, with 'exact match' and 'LIKE' as 'Where' params.

this is an example:

```
@find = Person.where(name: @f_name, surname: @f_surname, address: @f_address)
```

in the exaple, name and surname are exact match, but address must be something like "like %@f_address%", but ii can't goal it !!!

i tried also

```
@find = Person.where('name LIKE ? and surname LIKE ? and address LIKE ?', @f_name, @f_surname, '%#{@f_address}%')
```

But the result is the same!

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only issue is that you need double quote for interpolation. Try

```
"%#{@f_address}%"
```

Comment: For query with like params, is there a way to use couple "field/value" as in my first example?

Comment: I fear there isn't, I'm sorry.